# If you had a background check recently, will that expedite a second check?

Tags: hiring-process

Title pretty much says it all. If you applied at company A, and completed and passed their background check, will initiating a second background check at company B end up being faster because of the first one? Are BCs the sort of thing that is shared or do they essentially retread the same ground each time?

Comment: Kind of depends on your country. In the US, most background checks seem to be done by private companies. So, I guess it would depend on if Company A and Company B use the same background checking company.

Comment: It shouldn't. Even if the same background check company was used, it wouldn't be allowed to divulge to company B that you had already passed a background check with company A. So even if it completed the second check earlier because of this, it would still deliver it to the second company under the normal amount of time.

Comment: I think for real BG checks those done by government agencies previous checks will speed up the long process

Comment: @Neuromancer With security clearances, it can definitely speed things up (it also speeds up the paperwork — instead of doing a new SF-86, you just fill out a form saying what’s new since your last SF-86).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, most background checks seem to be done privately.
And every corporation / company runs its own process.
So, unless the companies are part of the same group, the background check will start from scratch every time.